# Predicting multiple categorical targets: Single model vs multiple models

Tags: predictive-modeling, multiclass-classification

I have to predict multiple categorical columns. Each one is a multi-class classification.

Should I train separate models to predict each column individually or create a new categorical column which combines all the output columns and train a single model?

What are the pros and cons of the two approaches?